# Count length of XML Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

With my JQuery call I can get the length of my Elements like this:

```
$(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').length
```

from that I will get how many times my Element is exisiting. My current State looks like this.

**Currently**:

```
$(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').length
```

Output> `8`

**What Output I want**:

Output> `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

How can I count my length up ?

Comment: Something like that = `console.log(Array($(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').length - 1 + 1).fill().map((item, index) => 1 + index).join(' '));` ?

Comment: yes exactly! Can you post it as an answer so i can upvote it ? explanation of what you did would help me alot, new to javascript/jquery

Comment: Done :)! you can see small explanation + some references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment you can use this fucntion

```js
const len = 8;
//const len = $(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').length;

console.log(Array(len).fill().map((_, index) => 1 + index).join(' '));
```

This function will take Max length (8 in this case) and [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) an array with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for create a string from the array itself.

Edit after comment:

```js
const len = 8;
//const len = $(xml).find('PARENT').find('CHILDREN').length;

console.log(Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, i) => 'a' + (i + 1)).join(' '));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to put a letter before every number ? tried putting it in like Array(len - 1 + 1).fill().map((item, index) => 1 + index).join("a"+' ') but then it will put the letter behind the number, and the last number wont get any letter, I want it like: "a1, a2, a3"

Comment: It can be just down with array.from....no fill, no map `Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, i) => i + 1).join(' ')`

Comment: `Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, i) => 'a' + (i + 1)).join(' ')`

Comment: :') <- when epascarello correct you